# Capture the execution logs in SSH client?

Tags: linux

can anyone please tell me how to capture the logs in SSH slient IDE which i use for making the build.I need to capture the logs into some text file to fix the warnings present.

Thanks in advance
Maddy

Comment: What do you want again? You need to state lot more details about what you are trying to do until the question makes sense to anybody else.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [script](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?script)

```
script
```

To record. Use script-replay to replay, or head over to Simon Tatham's page and use [IPBT](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/ipbt/)